# Does $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{3-\cos{i}}{i^{2/3}-2}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Need help determining whether the following infinite series converges or diverges, please state what convergence/divergence test was used.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{3-\cos{i}}{i^{2/3}-2}$$

Side Note: How can I make the equation bigger, it's kind of small with using only $$.

Comment: For bigger : use double dollar sign at each side.

Comment: The question would have been much more interesting without the $3$ there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

$$\;\frac{3-\cos i}{i^{2/3}-2}\ge\frac2{i^{2/3}}\ldots$$

Observe the series is positive for all but a finite number of summands.

Comment: bottom is always positive after 4. and how did you determine that 2  is always less than 3-cos(i)

Comment: and the series diverges by comparison test, to a diverging p series. Right?

Comment: could you be more explicit on how you prove that (3-cosi)/(i^(2/3)-2) >= 2/i^(2/3). I mean I don't think this always true for i >= 1

Comment: Yes, it is: $$-1\le\cos i\le 1\stackrel{\text{multiply by}\;-1}\iff 1\ge-\cos i\ge -1\stackrel{\text{add}\;3}\implies 4\ge3-\cos i\ge 2\ldots$$

Comment: I get that, but the ratio. how do you know that the ratio on the right is always smaller than the one on the left.

Comment: But @TedFlethuseo : $$i^{2/3}-2\le i^{2/3}\ldots !$$

Comment: Ok, I see it. Thx.